# Django filter to get more than one user in a model

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I created an app with referral system the challenge is that i want the referrer to see other models of his referred user say for example. investment platform  i want the referrer to see the persons the refereed main account(a model) and investment status(a model).

models

```
class TheMain(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    main_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    earning_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

the referral returns more than one user

```
class Referral(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    referral_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True)
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, 
    related_name="ref_by")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}- {self.code}'

    def get_referred(self):
        qs = Referral.objects.all()
        my_refs = []
        for referred in qs:
            if referred.referred_by == self.user:
                my_refs.append(referred)
        return my_refs
```

theviews

```
referral = Referral.objects.get(user=request.user)
my_ref = referral.get_referred()

refer_main = []


refer_invest =[]
for my in my_ref:
    main = TheMain.objects.filter(user = my.user)
    for ma in main:
        refer_main.append(ma)
```

`print(f'this is the mama {ma} and amount funded{ma.main_balance}'`)

the print statement returns all the referred name and amount paid

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
this is the mama user1 and amount funded1100
this is the mama user2 and amount funded800
this is the mama user and amount funded400.
```

the problem is loooping all these users to the template
i get this error when i use for loop

```
TypeError at /core/referral
'TheMain' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/core/referral
Django Version: 3.2.3
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'TheMain' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py, line 167, in render
Python Executable:  C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\HP\\Desktop\\brooker\\broker',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

but when its not in a loop it returns just one username

updated views as requested

```
def referral_page(request, *args, **kwargs):
    global invest_user, invest_name, invest_amount, invest_timer, main, that
    referral = Referral.objects.get(user=request.user)
    my_ref = referral.get_referred()

    refer_main = []


    refer_invest =[]
    for my in my_ref:
        main = TheMain.objects.filter(user = my.user)
        for ma in main:
            refer_main.append(ma)

        print(f'this is the mama {ma} and amount funded{ma.main_balance}')
        context = {
            'ref': ma

        }
        return render(request, 'referral/referral.html', context)
```

the templates

```
                                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered no-margin ">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr class="bg-pale-dark">
                                                <th class="text-center border-top-0">Username</th>
                                                <th class="text-center border-top-0">Account Status</th>
                                                <th class="text-center border-top-0"> Date Registered</th>
                                                <th class="text-center border-top-0">User's Investment</th>
                                                <th class="text-center border-top-0">Investment Status</th>
                                                <th class="text-center border-top-0">Ref Bonus</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
{#                                        {{ ref }}#}
                                        {% for r in ref %}
                                    {{ r }}
                                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Share your all views.py please

Comment: And please share the template that causes this precise error.

Comment: i just updated the referral

Answer (score 0):

As is in the exception, `'TheMain' object is not iterable`. You are referring to just one TheMain object, which is not a list, or a queryset.
Adding `ma` to the context just puts one Object of TheMain into the context.
Instead, add the the queryset `main` to the context. Like this

```
main = TheMain.objects.filter(user = my.user)
        for ma in main:
            refer_main.append(ma)

        context = {
            'ref': main
        }
```

Corroborating what I just explained,  I think it is the `refer_main` variable that should be in the context.

Furthermore,  I don't think it's okay to have a nested loop that adds values to the context on every iteration. Instead, on each iteration,  add the objects to a list. Then add that list to the context.
Finally, why is your return render in the `for loop` block ?